# Training in inference mode in seq-to-seq model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, sequence-to-sequence, encoder-decoder

This is apparently the code for seq2seq model with embedding that i wrote

```
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN, ), dtype='int32',)
    encoder_embedding = embed_layer(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_LSTM = LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_LSTM(encoder_embedding)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN, ))
    decoder_embedding = embed_layer(decoder_inputs)
    decoder_LSTM = LSTM(HIDDEN_DIM, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_LSTM(
        decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
    outputs = TimeDistributed(
        Dense(VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax'))(decoder_outputs)
    model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs)

    # defining inference model
    encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
    decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(None,))
    decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(None,))
    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_LSTM(
        decoder_embedding, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    outputs = TimeDistributed(
        Dense(VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax'))(decoder_outputs)
    decoder_model = Model(
        [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [outputs] + decoder_states)
    return model, encoder_model, decoder_model
```

we are using inference mode for predictions particularly encoder and decoder model, but i am not sure where the training is happening for the encoder and decoder?

## Edit 1

Code is build upon: https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/,
with added embedding layer and Time Distributed dense layer.
for more info on issue: [github repo](https://github.com/saransh7/encoder-decoder-keras)

Comment: you said 'apparently the code for seq2seq model with embedding that i wrote' - did you actually write it or copied from somewhere? please share references, your data and the context of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoder and decoder are trained simultaneously, or more precisely the model that is composed of these two is trained which in turn trains both of them (this is not GAN where you need some fancy training cycle)

If you look closely in the provided link, there is a section where the model is trained.

```py
# Run training
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

## Edit: from comments

If you look more closely, the "new" model that you are defining after fit consists of layers that have already been trained in the previous step. i.e Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states) both encoder_inputs and encoder_states were used during the initial training, you are just repackaging them.

Comment: Yes, sure you are pointing out right but this is for training mode, but for inference mode we are creating a new encoder and decoder model 
```
# Define sampling models
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You either train your model in the "training mode" or do the inference in the "inference" mode. You don't mix these 2 together.

Comment: If you want to augment your already trained model with some additional layers that have trainable parameters then you need to retrain the model with those additional layers included.

Comment: yes, got it, so when in inference mode we are not training(not updating weights)? is it right?

Comment: Yes that is right. But technically speaking there is no such thing as training or inference mode. What matters is what method you are calling. `fit` for training and `predict` for inference. If you are calling `predict`, no training is happening.

Comment: just after fit we are initializing our encoder_model `encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)`, then how come the trainied weights are carried forward. I know I am missing on something, this may seem naive but i am still not able to understand how we are using untrained encoder and decoder for for prediciton

Comment: If you look more closely, the "new" model that you are defining after `fit` consists of layers that have already been trained in the previous step. i.e `Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)` both `encoder_inputs` and `encoder_states` were used during the initial training, you are just repackaging them.